# UI Widget disabling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a widget and on button click I want the widget disabled.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("df.txt", { })
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    //register input widgets
    $("input").txt({ disabled: true });


    //Register button to disable/enable inputs
    $("button").click(function () {
        //$("input").txt("disable");
        $("input").txt("option", "disabled", true);
    });
});
```

I am using this [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-option) as reference.

It's not working, any help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $('input').attr("disabled", true);

 or

 $('input').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

Here we are setting the attribute disabled to true.

Comment: I think this will not work. Probably he is trying to do same thing as on this example: http://jqueryui.com/widget/

but i have no idea what is this txt() function.

Comment: txt is not a function it is a widget

Answer (score 1):

The base widget only toggles some classes when the `disabled` option changes.

If you want to actually disable the element your custom widget augments, you will have to override the `_setOption()` method and perform that operation explicitly:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("df.txt", {
        _setOption: function(key, value) {
            this._super(key, value);
            if (key == "disabled") {
                this.element.prop("disabled", !!value);
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can write something like:

```
// Register button to disable/enable inputs.
$("button").click(function() {
    var $inputs = $("input");
    $inputs.txt("option", "disabled", !$inputs.txt("option", "disabled"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_setOption: function (key, value) {

            if (key === "disabled") {
                if (value) { this._Disable(); }
                else { this._Enable(); }
            }

 _Enable: function () {
            this.element.removeAttr("disabled");
            this.element.addClass("enable");
        },

        _Disable: function () {
            this.element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            this.element.removeClass("enable");
        }
```

Comment: You're not calling the base class' implementation of `_setOption()` from your override, is this your intent? It might break the behavior of the base widget. It is also recommended to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to manipulate boolean DOM properties like `disabled`.